# Is a pion matter or antimatter?

Tags: antimatter, matter

It's made up of one quark and one antiquark. I can't seem to find anything that pays this question any attention? Also, what would be the antiparticle of it?

Comment: You might want to check out this site:   http://particleadventure.org/quarks_leptons.html   It does a nice job of outlining the basics.

Comment: Good question Jimmy, IMHO this sort of thing doesn't get enough attention. Note the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) where you can read this: _"In 1948, Lattes, Eugene Gardner, and their team first artificially produced pions at the University of California's cyclotron in Berkeley, California, by bombarding carbon atoms with high-speed alpha particles"._  Carbon atoms are matter, and so are alpha particles, which _"consist of two protons and two neutrons bound together into a particle identical to a helium nucleus"_.

Answer (score 4):

Since the quark content of the $\pi^+$ is $u\bar d$ and that of the $\pi^-$ is $\bar u d$, the two charged pions are antiparticles of each other.

Since the quark content of the $\pi^0$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u\bar u - d\bar d)$, it is its own antiparticle.

For none of the pions does it make sense to speak of "matter" or "antimatter", as none of them constitutes ordinary matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

The antiparticle of a pi+ is the pi-, and vice verso. The antiparticle of the pi0 is itself.

Antimatter as a term is applicable to fermions,  quarks, electrons, muons, taus and their neutrinos.  Protons and neutrons are particles because they are composed out of valence quarks. Antiprotons and antineutrons are antiparticles because they are composed out of valence antiquarks . For bosons it is a matter of convention and of the specific reaction under consideration.